# update_post_meta() throws Uncaught error: Cannot create duplicate attribute

Tags: post-meta, metabox

In my plugin I'm creating a post of a custom post type. Immediately after creation I'm trying to update some of the metadata that I've defined in metaboxes for this CPT. Upon execution of the code, the post gets created, but I get a fatal error.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot create duplicate attribute

I can trace it back to the use of the update_post_meta() function. If I remove this, the code runs without errors (but doesn't do what I want).

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

```
            //Create new post of custom post type match
            $author_id = 1;
            $match_name = $match_details['NoInTournament'] . ":" . $match_details['TeamAName'] . " vs. " . $match_details['TeamBName'];
            $slug = sanitize_title($match_name); //Will come from retrieved data
            $title = esc_html($match_details["RoundName"] . '/' . $match_name); //Will come from retrieved data
            $post_content = '<p>[rat-match-details match="' . $match . '"]</p>';

            $page = get_page_by_title( $title , OBJECT, 'match');

            if( $page == null) {
                // Create the page
                // Set the page ID so that we know the page was created successfully
                $post_id = wp_insert_post(
                    array(
                        'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
                        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
                        'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
                        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
                        'post_title'        =>  $title,
                        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                        'post_type'         =>  'match',
                        'post_content'      =>  $post_content
                    )
                    );
            } else {
                // The page exists
                $post_id = wp_update_post(
                    array(
                        'ID'                =>  $page->ID,
                        'post_content'      =>  $post_content
                    )
                    );
            } // end if

            //update metadata
            //Currently gives fatal error: "Cannot create duplicate attribute" ==> What is the cause?

            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rat-match-tournament', get_the_title(get_the_ID()) );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rat-match-number-vis', $match );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rat-match-number-tournament', $match_details['NoInTournament'] );
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rat-match-round', $match_details["RoundName"] );
```

**EDIT**
Here's the full error message I see on the page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot create duplicate attribute in /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:4742 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php(2691): map_deep(Object(SimpleXMLElement), 'stripslashes_fr...') #1 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php(5342): stripslashes_deep(Object(SimpleXMLElement)) #2 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/meta.php(182): wp_unslash(Object(SimpleXMLElement)) #3 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(2061): update_metadata('post', 1825, 'rat-match-round', Object(SimpleXMLElement), '') #4 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/plugins/referee-assesment/includes/rat-shortcodes.php(113): update_post_meta(1825, 'rat-match-round', Object(SimpleXMLElement)) #5 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(325): rat_shortcode_matches(Array, '<p>Hello World!...', 'rat-list-tourna...') #6 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #7 in /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4742
```

and the one in the wordpress debug.log:

```
[23-Aug-2019 08:15:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot create duplicate attribute in /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:4742
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php(2691): map_deep(Object(SimpleXMLElement), 'stripslashes_fr...')
#1 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php(5342): stripslashes_deep(Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#2 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/meta.php(182): wp_unslash(Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#3 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(2061): update_metadata('post', 1825, 'rat-match-round', Object(SimpleXMLElement), '')
#4 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-content/plugins/referee-assesment/includes/rat-shortcodes.php(113): update_post_meta(1825, 'rat-match-round', Object(SimpleXMLElement))
#5 /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(325): rat_shortcode_matches(Array, '<p>Hello World!...', 'rat-list-tourna...')
#6 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
#7 in /srv/www/wordpress-default/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4742
```

*Note: I know it's not smart to create pages in a shortcode, but it's a first PoC for something bigger and I'll move code around to appropriate places*

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? "Cannot create duplicate attribute" is not a standard PHP error, and does not exist in WordPress at all. `update_post_meta()` would not throw it. In fact it seems to be a SimpleXML error. What happens in your code _after_ `update_post_meta()`. Are you sure the error isn't caused by something later? What line actually throws the error? The error message should say.

Comment: I see the error message in Wordpress debug log and on the page that is loaded. I do see a reference indeed to SimpleXML. I've included the full error message in the original post

Comment: Looking at the stack trace the problem seems to be that `$match_details["RoundName"]` is an XML element, not text. Try `var_dump()`-ing it and seeing if it's what you expected.

Comment: Thanks, that was it indeed. Fixed my way around it.